# Get Specific Object on Restful Path with Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My code:

#### api/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from api import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^entries", views.EntryList.as_view(), name="api-entries-list"),
    url(r"^entries/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$", views.EntrySingle.as_view(), name="api-entry")
]
```

#### api/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import Http404

from blog.models import Entry
from api.serializers import EntrySerializer

from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

# Create your views here.
class EntryList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        entries = Entry.objects.all()
        serializer = EntrySerializer(entries, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = EntrySerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class EntrySingle(APIView):
    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return Entry.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Entry.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        entry = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = EntrySerializer(entry)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        entry = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = EntrySerializer(entry, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        entry = self.get_object(pk)
        entry.delete()
        return Response(status=HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

#### api/serializers.py

```
from blog.models import *
from cvitae.models import *
from activities.models import *

from rest_framework import serializers

class EntrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ("title", "slug")
```

I have an app called `blog` which contains `Entry` models having `title`, `content` and `slug` in short. I wanted to use *Django Rest Framework* to get, put or delete my entries. The code is as above. When I trigger `/api/entries`, it is okay, it gives all `Entry` model instances in database.

```
[
    {
        "title": "And Maybe This is Another One",
        "slug": "and-maybe-this-is-another-one"
    },
    {
        "title": "Another Topic Here",
        "slug": "another-topic-here"
    },
    {
        "title": "An Example Title",
        "slug": "an-example-title"
    }
]
```

However, when I exactly want to have an `Entry` instance by a `pk` value, I still get the same output, which means I still get all objects. I don't know where I did wrong.

---

## Environment

- django 1.9.5
- python 3.5.1
- djangorestframework 3.3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to terminate your first regex, otherwise it matches everything beginning with "entries".

```
r"^entries/$"
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, you saved me. I can accept this as valid after 4 mins later.